# How to remove modules which are in use?

Tags: raspberry-pi, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm using ov5647 MIPI camera in raspberry pi,
I make ov5640 driver as dynamic, now I try to remove ov5647 module with

```
sudo rmmod ov5647
```

but what I got is this:

```
$ sudo rmmod ov5647.ko
rmmod: ERROR: Module ov5647 is in use
```

this is lsmod output:

```
$ lsmod | grep ov5647
ov5647                 20480  1
v4l2_fwnode            24576  2 bcm2835_unicam,ov5647
v4l2_async             24576  3 bcm2835_unicam,v4l2_fwnode,ov5647
videodev              249856  10 bcm2835_unicam,rpivid_hevc,bcm2835_isp,ov5647,bcm2835_codec,videobuf2_common,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2,v4l2_async
mc                     49152  10 bcm2835_unicam,rpivid_hevc,bcm2835_isp,ov5647,bcm2835_codec,videobuf2_common,videodev,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2,v4l2_async
```

how to remove ov5647 module which is in use?

Comment: Your options are either (a) figure out what's using the module and stop it or (b) reboot. (a) isn't always possible.

Comment: Try `lsof /dev/video*` or `sudo /dev/video*` to see which process(es) is/are holding the video device(s) open. (You might need to install the `lsof` package first.)

Comment: @Ian Abbott want to remove the ov5647 module even if camera is connected.

Comment: You could use the `rmmod -f` option (if the kernel was built with `CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD=y`), but that will leave the system in an inconsistent state, possibly resulting in a system crash.